# How can I count the number of messages in one channel of each user?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I want to code a discord bot with the discord.js ... But in the documentation, I don't found a function to count the number of messages in a channel of each user... Is there a function to use the searchbar with filters like an user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The search is not ( yet ) avaible for Bots.

You could [`Channel#fetchMessages`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannel?scrollTo=fetchMessages) but this would be very Api intensive.

Best way would be to get a database and increment it when the user sends a message, but that will only count messages when the bot is running.

Answer (score 0):

The above works. But if you did not implement the feature into the bot. One way is to do a search using in: channel(whatever channel you want) and it will show you the result count which is technically the message count in that channel. Hope it helped.