# How would I implement a field which counts the amount of messages sent by a user in an RichEmbed?

Tags: discord.js

I'm trying to create a profile card for users in my discord server, where they type the command ';profile' and then a richembed will show some stats. I am very new to coding (started about an hour ago, so be wary of my noob-ness). How would i calculate the number of messages sent in all channels?

This is my current code for the embed.

```
 switch(args[0]){
        case 'profile':
            const profile = new discord.RichEmbed()
                .setTitle('**Profile**')
                .addField('**Name**', message.author.username, true)
                .addField('Discriminator', message.author.discriminator, true)
                .addField('Messages sent', '12', true)
                .setColor(0x5704e5)
                .setThumbnail(message.author.avatarURL)
                .setAuthor(message.author.tag, message.author.avatarURL)
            message.channel.sendEmbed(profile);
        break; 
    }
```

I would want a field titled 'messages sent' with the total messages sent by the user.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I count the number of messages in one channel of each user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55673386/how-can-i-count-the-number-of-messages-in-one-channel-of-each-user)

Comment: You will need a Database and if somebody sends a Message +1 his count.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no way to ideally log message count prior to your +1 counter being active. So everybody will have to start from 0.

What I recommend is using a database (noob friendly ones such as firebase can be easy to use as they have a friendly interface website) and just storing a +1 to the message count of each user every time they send a message.